# Multiple Profiles For Spring Integration Tests?

Tags: spring, maven, testing

I need different profiles for a few things. First we have the issue of my databases. When I run local tests I expect to use one datasource. When I run an acceptance profile (for a CI acceptance build), I expect to use a different datasource. Finally, when I run acceptance not in test I expect to use a third datasource. How I imagined this would work is.

```
/src/main/resources/application.properties
/src/main/resources/application-acceptance.properties
/src/test/resources/application-test.properties
/src/test/resources/application-acceptance-test.properties
```

However when I run `mvn clean install -Dspring.profiles.active=acceptance` it does not run the `application-accepatnce-test.properties`.

Finally, I would like to be able to run a mvn install while running the tests but not the integrations test. For this I imagine I would add a `-Dspring.profiles.active=nointegration` and then simply add an `@ActiveProfiles('!nointegration')` on the integration tests.

I've had no luck with either of these. Is it even possible to get profiles on test runs?

If it helps I am using Spring Boot 1.3.0.RELEASE.

EDIT:

On my integration tests I have `@ActiveProfiles("test")`. Is there any way to generate the profile here based on the java-opt spring.profiles.active?

Comment: So you are passing parameters to Maven! and you expect your tests to honor them. Those tests never see the parameters because, as mentioned in the first sentence, those are passed to Maven NOT the tests. Next to that looks a bit dangerous to run tests with different settings in different environments, how are you going guarantee that each will deliver the same results?

Comment: The tests are only really testing the schema is working correctly, and the schema is managed by flyway, ensuring consistency across environments. I don't want to use a flag for all tests, only integration tests which start up spring. I figured since spring was starting up, I would have the ability to configure it to change the datasource.